# PHP arrays - sorting (highest to lowest) by value calculated outside the array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, directory

**Problem:**

I need to sort the array *(contents shown in bulleted list in the order they appear within the array)* into order of the numbers on the left-hand side (highest to lowest).

The numbers correspond to the number of divisions within the directory path on the right-hand side (They are not stored within the array currently...).

My problem arises as I have no clue how to sort the array by the values given in the example - as they are outside the array. I have tried playing with multi-dimensional arrays, however this has just lead to more confusion!

**Output on screen due to code listed below:**

- 6 # C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\planner\import\homeworktasks
- 5 # C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\planner\import
- 7 # C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\planner\import\homeworktasks\11
- 7 # C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\planner\import\homeworktasks\15
- 7 # C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\planner\import\homeworktasks\17
- 7 # C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\planner\import\homeworktasks\9
- 7 # C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\planner\import\homeworktasks\test
- 8 # C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\planner\import\homeworktasks\test\inside

**Code:**

```
<?php
//make all items in the array unique
$dir_list = array_unique($dir_list);
//create new array to sort into
$dir_list_sort = array();
//for each item in the array
foreach($dir_list as $dir)
{
    //find depth of array
    $dir_depth = substr_count($dir , DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    //stuff that is written to the page separated by a #
    echo $dir_depth." # ".$dir."<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Putting both values into the array, “multi-dimensional” as you call it, would be the easiest solution indeed – then you just need a tiny little self-written comparison function that you can use with `usort`, and you’re done.

Comment: Management of the arrays could likely be improved with the way you create the array. Can you show the code where you generate the array?

Comment: As an alternative to a multidimensional array, `array_multisort` with two arguments (array of counts and original) would also naturally work here. And it's one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PHP's [`usort()`](http://www.php.net/usort) function. `usort()` "will sort an array by its values using a user-supplied comparison function." [(PHP.net)](http://www.php.net/usort)

You'll have to write a function that can compare two values and returns either -1, 0 or 1.

```
<?php

// This is just a shortcut for determining the directory depth
function dir_depth($directory_name)
{
    return substr_count($directory_name, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}

// Takes two values ($a and $b) and returns either -1, 0 or 1
function compare($a, $b)
{
    $depth_a = dir_depth($a);
    $depth_b = dir_depth($b));

    if ($depth_a == $depth_b) {
        // If they have the same depth, return 0
        return 0;
    }

    // If depth_a is smaller than depth_b, return -1; otherwise return 1
    return ($depth_a < $depth_b) ? -1 : 1;
}

// Now we can sort the array.
// usort() needs two parameters:
// 1. the array that will be reordered
// 2. the name of the function that compares two values
usort($dir_list, 'compare');

// Now display the list
foreach ($dir_list as $dir) {
    // here we can use our dir_depth() function again
    echo dir_depth($dir) . ' # ' . $dir . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need multi-dimentional arrays for this. A normal `usort` will do the trick

```
usort($dir_list, 'compareDirectoryDepth');

function compareDirectoryDepth($dir1, $dir2) {
    $c1 = substr_count($dir1 , DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    $c2 = substr_count($dir2 , DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

    return ($c1 == $c2 ? 0 : ($c1 < $c2 ? -1 : 1));
}
```

Off course this can be optimized a bit so substr_count is called a bit less